# Can an img tag render a PIL object?

Tags: image, flask, python-imaging-library

I am using Flask to obtain an image using request.files.get and then manipulating it with PIL. Can I render this PIL object (as a variable in the render function) with the template's img tag's src attribute or will it return an error? In this case, what can I do to make it compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either

1. save the PIL image to a file somewhere that is served by your web server and let the `src` attribute of the `img` element point to that file, or
2. embed the image data into the `src` value as a [`data:`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2397) URL (though I must confess I don’t know how well this works in practice, especially not with anything larger than thumbnail-sized images), or
3. let the `src` URL point to a URL which is handled by Flask and where Flask returns image data, just as it normally returns HTML text.

Answer (score -1):

No, the img tag cannot render a PIL object.

Comment: Ok, then how can I make it work? I'm essentially placing numbers over the image so any alternative/workaround would be appreciated

Comment: <code>from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('image.jpg')
</code>